# Guard Problem--> It's not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular16, angular-guards

## Guard related problem

```
export const canActiveChildGuard: CanActivateChildFn = (childRoute, state) => {
  const router = inject(Router);
  // const router = new Router;
  console.log("child");

  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (token) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    router.navigate(['Home'])
    return false;
  }
};
```

**angular.module.ts file**

```
{
    path: 'Courses',
    component: CourseComponent,
    canActivateChild: [canActiveChildGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'Course/:id', component: OneCourseComponent }
    ]
},
```

I try to prevent the execution if token is not there in the local storage. My canActiveChild guard would not called i don't know how.

I want if token is there in the local storage then and then only user will access child route otherwise not.

I'm facing this problem in angular16 version.`

Comment: Which path are you navigating to? You are using `canActivateChild` so the guard will only fire when navigation to one of the **children**, in your case `/Course/:id`. It will **not** be fired when navigating to the parent `/Course`.